# Value being reset in while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, pic

I am very new to this programming, trying to seta  project up on proteus to add, minus and set an alarm through the use of buttons connected to a PIC. Issue is the count is not saving after the while loop and is being reset.
 - button1= ADD, button2=MINUS, button 1+2+3 = ALARM
 - cant figure out why overall count is being reset to 0
 - Any help would be amazing

```
#include <main.h>
#ZERO_RAM

int a = 0;
int state;
char data = 'y';
short int flags[3];
char uart_rd;

void main()
{
    setup_wdt(WDT_1MS); //~1.0 ms reset

    port_a_pullups(0xFF); // Defining PORTA as pullup Resistors

    printf("program start" nr); //<------keeps resetting value to 0 HERE

    while (TRUE) // infinite loop
    {
        if (!input(PIN_A1)) // add button
        {
            if (!flags[0])
            {
                flags[0] = 1;
                a++; // add one to overall count
                printf("ADDED, Total= %dnr", a); // prints count
            }
        }
        else
        {
            flags[0] = 0;
        }
        if (!input(PIN_A2)) // minus button
        {
            if (!flags[1])
            {
                flags[1] = 1;
                a--; // take away 1 from count
                printf("MINUS, Total= %dnr", a); // print count
            }
        }
        else
        {
            flags[1] = 0;
        }
        if ((!input(PIN_A1)) && (!input(PIN_A2)) && (!input(PIN_A3))) // all buttons     equal alarm
        {
            printf("ALARM HAS BEEN SETnr"); // if all buttons are held constant alarm
            // is printed through Terminal
        }
        else
        {
            flags[2] = 0;
            output_high(PIN_A0); // led goes high
            delay_ms(500); // flashing LED every cycle
            output_low(PIN_A0); // led goes low
            printf("Overall Count= %dnr", a); // printf overall count
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: Keep resetting *what* value? What "count"?

Comment: To difficult to read.  Next...

Comment: sorry, there is an overall value (a) which is being altered by the inputs being pressed on proteus. I dont want the value to return to 0 but it is that is what I was trying to ask

Comment: Your code is unreadable due to the poor indentation - you need to fix that if you want a useful answer. And your code is incomplete. You have not even shown how `a` is declared. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: first ever time posting on a coding forum my apologies, trying to adjust as it goes

Comment: You should use `"main.h"` instead of `<main.h>`.  And what is `#ZERO_RAM`? YOU should include your header file to make the example compilable.

Comment: Please give the input that you used for testing and the output from the program.

Comment: Identation is not for fun, nor to please us or your teacher. It's mainly for _you_ so you can read and understand your own program. And please don't post compelentary information about your question in comments butg _edit_ your question.

Comment: again sorry like I said sorry First every time posting, by the way I fixed it. It was the timing of the Watchdogtimer resetting the process. Thanks to the people who actually tried to help rather than lecture me.

Comment: Identation has been improved a bit but it's still poor.

Comment: After you fix indentation take some read on **debouncing**.

Comment: I indented the code fully; should be visible once it is approved.

Comment: You say: `printf("program start" nr); //<------keeps resetting value to 0 HERE` but it can't be resetting it everytime there because it is in main, which is called only once.

Comment: Oh. And just wth is `nr`? Now I wasted my time in writing an answer which might not be related to this particular problem. Though as you can tell from the answer, this code has a great number of bugs/LOC.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following bugs:

- You never initialize `flags` anywhere. Sure, static storage duration variables are required by the standard to be initialized to zero. But in embedded systems, there is an incredibly common non-standard extension which removes the "zero-out" part from the start up code. When you create a project you often get an option "minimal startup" or "standard C". Therefore, always initialize all your variables manually in run-time before using them. Robust embedded code makes no assumptions about the default values of variables in neither `.data`nor `.bss` segments.
- You haven't implemented any debouncing. Please check some beginner tutorial about how to read buttons in embedded systems, to avoid problems with the *electro-mechanical signal bounce*. The signal bounce causes the code `flags[0] = 0;` to get executed.
- Whenever someone presses a button, your condition for increasing the counter remains true for as long as the button is pressed. The microcontroller is fast enough to run that code many thousand times over during the time a slow human keeps the button pressed. Instead, you should only increase the counter when the button goes from inactive to active. Obviously, the code doing this needs to be located *after* the debouncing.